# How to Make Footer Stay Inline with Content?

Tags: html, css

[On this site,](http://www.yogadetoxretreat.co.uk/) you'll see that the footer is stuck on the left. This is the CSS:

```
#footer {
width: 800px;
clear:both;
float:right;
position:relative;
left:-50%;}
```

Please let me know why this might be.

Thanks,

Tara

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should keep it simple and use:

```
#footer {
    width: 800px;
    clear: both;
    margin: 0 auto; /* center it */
}
```

This is exactly the same technique as you've already used successfully on `.container`, for instance.

Comment: Thanks @thirtydot, that appears to have centered it; but now the <hr> is 100% of the page rather than 800px for some reason...

Comment: +1 Simples is the best way.. @Tara try putting `width: 800px !important`

Comment: @Tara: You've pasted it a bit wonky. This is what you have: `#footer {
 #footer {
 width: 800px;
 clear: both;
 margin: 0 auto; /* center it */
}
}`.

Comment: I'm sorry, but `margin:auto` is interpreted differently by the browser. Sometimes it simply means `margin:0px`.

Comment: @Oltarus: `margin: 0 auto` works fine and is mechanism centering almost every centered site on the Internet. http://css-discuss.incutio.com/wiki/Centering_Block_Element#Centering_with_auto-margins

Answer (score 0):

To center the footer:

```
#footer {
  width:800px;
  position:absolute;
  padding-left:50%;
  margin-left:-400px;
  bottom:0px;
}
```

Comment: that is some really wierd styling? padding left 50% \and margin right 400px? eeee ? what?

Comment: @ppumkin I'm very sorry, it was a typo. I meant `-400px` and `margin-left`. Fixed!

Answer (score 0):

```
#footer {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:0px;
    width:100%;
}
```

Example demo : http://jsbin.com/ecolun/3